# tcpClient sends file to tcpServer not completely or "damaged"

Tags: c#, file, client-server, tcpclient, tcplistener

I'm working on a little console "Send file to Server" program.

The client (tcpClient) reads a file from his folder and sends it to the server (tcpServer), and the server receives it and writes this file into his folder.

I still have 2 problems:

- If the client sends a ~19MB `.txt` file (which is full of random chars but no blanks!) to the server, the server receives the file, writes a ~19MB `.txt` file in his folder, but the `.txt` file in the server folder contains only in the first few lines of the original file, and the large rest contains only blanks. The `.txt` file is on the server side not complete...
- If the client sends a 9KB `.png` file, the server receives it, writes it to his folder. But if I try to open this `.png` file from the server folder, then I get an error message which says, that this file is too large or maybe damaged... (the `.png` file in the server folder has the right `.png` extension and the typical icon).

Server:

```
public void recieveFile() {
    NetworkStream nws = clientconnection.GetStream();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(nws);
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(nws);

    // Recieve filename
    string filename = sr.ReadLine().Remove(0, 10);

    // Recieve filesize
    long filesize = Convert.ToInt64(sr.ReadLine().Remove(0, 10));

    Byte[] fileBytes = new Byte[filesize];
    nws.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
    nws.Close();

    var a = File.OpenWrite(filename);
    a.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
    a.Flush();
    a.Close();
}
```

Client:

```
public void sendFileToServer(String filename) {
    var a = File.OpenRead(filename);

    FileInfo fo = new FileInfo(filename);
    long filesize = fo.Length;

    // Write file into fileBytes-Array
    Byte[] fileBytes = new Byte[filesize];
    a.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
    a.Close();

    // Send filename to server
    sw.WriteLine("Filename: " + filename);
    sw.Flush();

    // Send filesize to server
    sw.WriteLine("Filesize: " + filesize);
    sw.Flush();

    // Send fileBytes to server
    NetworkStream nws = clientConnection.GetStream();
    nws.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
    nws.Flush();
    nws.Close();

    sw.Close();
    sr.Close();
    clientConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: The word is properly spelled **receive** in English (not "recieve")

Comment: Implement `using` blocks for your `Stream`, `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` instances.

Comment: @ John Saunders: You're right, but it still do not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My startpost-version is full of several mistakes. Here the now 100% working version:

Client:

```
                    public void sendFileToServer(String filename) {

                        var a = File.OpenRead(filename);

                        FileInfo fo = new FileInfo(filename);
                        long filesize = fo.Length;

                        // Send filename to server
                        sw.WriteLine("Filename: " + filename);
                        sw.Flush();

                        // Send filesize to server
                        sw.WriteLine("Filesize: " + filesize);
                        sw.Flush();

                        // Write file into fileBytes-Array and sends it in parts
                        Byte[] fileBytes = new Byte[1024];
                        long count = filesize;
                        while (count > 0) {
                            int recieved = a.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                            a.Flush();
                            nws.Write(fileBytes, 0, recieved);
                            nws.Flush();
                            count -= recieved;
                        }
                        a.Close();
                        nws.Close();

                        sw.Close();
                        sr.Close();
                        clientConnection.Close();

                    }
```

Server:

```
            public void recieveFile() {

                        NetworkStream nws = clientconnection.GetStream();
                        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(nws);
                        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(nws);

                        // Recieve filename
                        string filename = sr.ReadLine().Remove(0, 10);

                        // Recieve filesize
                        long filesize = Convert.ToInt64(sr.ReadLine().Remove(0, 10));

                        long count = filesize;
                        Byte[] fileBytes = new Byte[1024];
                        var a = File.OpenWrite(filename);
                        while (count > 0) {
                            int recieved = nws.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                            nws.Flush();
                            a.Write(fileBytes, 0, recieved);
                            a.Flush();
                            count -= recieved;
                        }
                        nws.Close();
                        a.Close();

                        sr.Close();
                        sr.Close();
                        clientconnection.Close();

                    }
```